# How do you sync JavaScript animations with the tempo of a song, without building an "audio visualizer"?

Tags: javascript, audio, animation

From my basic understanding, JavaScript audio visualizers are reflecting the music based on the actual sound waves.  I would like to build something like a metronome (http://bl.ocks.org/1399233), where I animate some DOM element every `x` beats.

The way I'm doing this now is I manually figure out the tempo of the song, say it's 120bpm, then I convert that to milliseconds to run a `setInterval` callback.  But that doesn't seem to work because the browser performance causes it to be imprecise.  Is there a better way to make sure a callback is executed exactly at the same tempo a song is in?

If not, what are some other strategies to sync JavaScript animations with a song's tempo that's not an audio visualizer?

Update: something like this it looks like?  https://github.com/bestiejs/benchmark.js/blob/master/benchmark.js#L1606

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem, in that `setInterval` could not be relied on to "keep time" over a long period.  My solution was the snippet below: (in coffee script, compiled js is in the link at the end)

It provides a drop in replacement for setInetrval that will stay very close to keeping time.  With it, you can do this:

```js
accurateInterval(1000 * 60 / bpm, callbackFunc);
```

See my use case and example that syncs visuals with a provided BPM to a youtube video here: http://squeegy.github.com/MandalaTron/?bpm=64&vid=EaAzRm5MfY8&vidt=0.5&fullscreen=1

accurateInterval code:

```coffee
# Accurate Interval, guaranteed not to drift!
# (Though each call can still be a few milliseconds late)
window.accurateInterval = (time, fn) ->
  
  # This value is the next time the the timer should fire.
  nextAt = new Date().getTime() + time
  
  # Allow arguments to be passed in in either order.
  if typeof time is 'function'
    [fn, time] = [time, fn]
  
  # Create a function that wraps our function to run.  This is responsible for
  # scheduling the next call and aborting when canceled.
  wrapper = ->
    nextAt += time
    wrapper.timeout = setTimeout wrapper, nextAt - new Date().getTime()
    fn()
  
  # Clear the next call when canceled.
  wrapper.cancel = -> clearTimeout wrapper.timeout
  
  # Schedule the first call.
  setTimeout wrapper, nextAt - new Date().getTime()
  
  # Return the wrapper function so cancel() can later be called on it.
  return wrapper
```

get the coffee script and js here: https://gist.github.com/1d99b3cd81d610ac7351

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question though. You might be able to get the tempo exactly right, but you're off by a fixed time because the music took some unknown time to load; I don't think there is a guaranteed way to know when the music starts playing.

Answer (score 3):

This post might be relevant:

- [Is there a more accurate way to create a Javascript timer than setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196027/is-there-a-more-accurate-way-to-create-a-javascript-timer-than-settimeout)

The gist is that you run a function in your `setInterval()` slightly faster than your tempo, for example, every 100ms. Long example short, you can track whether or not it's time to play a "beat" by checking the value of `(new Date()).getMilliseconds()` and seeing if the equivalent of one beat in milliseconds has passed instead of relying on the not-so-accurate `setTimeout` or `setInterval` functions.

Even with that, music itself, unless generated by a computer, might not have perfect or consistent tempo, so accounting for mistimed beats could be a hurdle for you, which may be why using audio analysis to find where the actual beats are going to happen could be a better route.