# More efficient way other than setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

The time delay given in `setTimeout()` works differently for Windows and Ubuntu?

Why is that?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Browser dependent not OS dependent

Comment: @aaronman Had run the code in firefox in 2 different systems with windows and ubuntu OS.

Comment: what do you mean it works DIFFERENTLY ? what're you observing? the call theoretically doesn't work differently on different browsers NOR on different operating systems.

Comment: @aaronman why do you think setTimeout behavior is browser dependent ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/196027/1283215

Comment: @Ahmed Masud I had to put more time on windows to run the code whereas lesser time in ubuntu to run the code correctly.

Comment: setTimeout is not an accurate timer. @Hussain pointed out a very nice set of answers.  look at the answer BELOW the accepted answer with there is a reference to this:  http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/  which may be something you want to use

Comment: @AhmedMasud they are likely very similar but each browser has it's own javascript implementation

Comment: From your comment above: "_I had to put more time on windows to run the code..._" This suggests to me that you might be using some kind of delay to "_get your code to work_."  That's something you should never do.  In JavaScript callback functions are generally used when you need to "_call function X_" after "_event Y has completed_".  Google around about callback functions or open another question (or edit this one) with some simple example code to demonstrate what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The time given in setTimeout() is not guaranteed.

There are several reasons for that:

- The eventQueue system of JavaScript
- Timer accuracy depending on the OS and/or browser (is between 1ms and 20ms)

I wrote a blog post about time in JavaScript at

http://www.codebullets.com/is-time-relative-in-javascript-1365 
about this topic

**Better way for what?**

It depends what you want to do. Also take a look at RequestAnimationFrame (http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/), maybe this is for you.

Comment: How JavaScript Timers Work, John Resig
http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: Timer resolution in browsers, Nicholas C. Zakas, 
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/12/14/timer-resolution-in-browsers/

Comment: Timers in HTML5, http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers

Answer (score 1):

`requestAnimationFrame` *will* trigger for each monitor VBLANK gap if requested before the next VBLANK.

That way it is a very accurate timer. However, it triggers up to 60 times per seconds and it won't be very accurate if you spend more than the 16.7ms time-budget you get before you need to call it again.

If your functions operates within this time-budget, `requestAnimationFrame` will be most accurate you can get access to from Javascript.

It's triggered almost the same way as `setTimeout`:

```
function myLoop() {

    //... < 16.7ms to finish work...

    requestAnimationFrame(myLoop);
}
```

Note: you will need to use prefixes in some browsers or a polyfill (see chris' answer for link).

Comment: I'd use `requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame || prefixes || setTimeout` for a polyfill.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` won't fire if the browser window/tab is not visible, will  it?

Comment: @JanDvorak it will, but at reduced rate (typical half or 1/30s)..

Comment: My guess is the OP is just using an arbitrary delay to get some code to work after something has loaded (or completed)... Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think the actual precision of the timer is his issue.  Of course it would be nice if he clarified something.