# Using Moment.js and getting the page to update to show seconds

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Bear with my crappy JS skills, but I'm trying to get a page to update with moment.js so it continually shows the seconds count.

I have this:

```
function update_time(){ 

 var now = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');

$('.timer').append(now);

setTimeout(update_time, 1000);

})();
```

Yet I'm not sure how to get it to work correctly. I'm pretty sure I'm not closing something correctly, or even if I have the function formatting correctly.

Comment: Not sure if it's due to error in copy-paste - but shouldn't there be a '(' before function? Also, can you provide more information on how is it working incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be two issues here.

First, your self-invoking function needs to be surrounded by parentheses; you seem to be missing the first opening parenthesis as @linstantnoodles pointed out.

Second, appending the time will keep appending the time text to the given node every second. You probably want to *replace* the content of `.timer`, so you should use [`jQuery.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/UxULk/).

```
(function update_time(){ 
    var now = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');
    $('.timer').text(now);
    setTimeout(update_time, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: I think you mean [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). It might not make a difference in this case, but `.html()` should only be used with an HTML-encoded string.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Yeah, I'm piecing together some items from other resources and I haven't really worked with custom JS functions that much. I wasn't really sure how to set it up from scratch. But this really helps me understand it better and it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Good call, @user113215. Either works, but `.text` is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function update_time(){        
  var now = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');    
  //displaying the timer    
  $('.timer').html(now);    
  //Keeping update in seconds    
  setTimeout(update_time, 1000);    
};

//Initiate first
setTimeout(update_time, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on the method setTimeout() when doing clock work ([see question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196027/is-there-a-more-accurate-way-to-create-a-javascript-timer-than-settimeout)). Instead use the date object like in [the sample at W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock) or see script like http://flipclockjs.com/ for accurate timers.