# JavaScript settimeout Inconsistancies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, setinterval

## setInterval() Inconsistencies

I am trying to create an object that works like a stopwatch, but there is a 100 millisecond difference between **Chrome** and Firefox browsers.  The code and test below fails in both **Safari** and **Chrome** but passes in Firefox.

#### Question: Why does this happen?

#### Questions: How to achieve Consistency with this object across browsers?

You can run this [SAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/yiren/3/edit) in several browsers and watch the test pass or fail.  The sample is on JSBIN so you can also make code changes to it.

### Timer Object (SUT)

I've built a **Timer** object that essentially works like a stopwatch:

```
function Timer() {
  this.interval = null;
  this.time = 0;
}

Timer.prototype.start = function () {
  var self = this;
  this.interval = setInterval(function () {
    self.time += 100;
  }, 100);
};

Timer.prototype.stop = function () {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
};
```

### Timer Test (jasmine)

This test starts and stops the timer.  It fails in Chrome but passes in FireFox.

```
describe("Timer", function () {

  it("should stop and record time accurately", function (done) {
    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.start();
    setTimeout(function () {
      expect(timer.time).toEqual(600);
      done();
    }, 600);
  });

});
```

Comment: there isn't much you can do to fix that.

Comment: timeouts aren't exact. they're best-effort for scheduling. you cannot hope to have perfect accuracy with them.

Comment: If you need exact timing, then this isn't the way you're going to be able to do it. Windows, OSX and Linux are not real-time operating systems.

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicate, see also [What is the reason JavaScript setTimeout is so inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097421/what-is-the-reason-javascript-settimeout-is-so-inaccurate)

Comment: (I originally closed this as a duplicate of [Is there a more accurate way to create a Javascript timer than setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196027/is-there-a-more-accurate-way-to-create-a-javascript-timer-than-settimeout), but I see that it's perhaps slightly more nuanced than that -- I think a good answer here would explain the relationship between the behaviors described in that answer and use it to explain exactly what is happening here.)

Answer (score 0):

Just set `this.time` to `100` in object constructor if webkit and `0` if gecko.

Comment: This is a good fix... but why is there a difference?  webkit works consistently once the time is already set.  Is there a difference in the way this function is processed between the two browsers?

Comment: I don't really know, but should be, while it works different.