# Image unable to re-appear in SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

***Functionality:***

Users will tap on an image(group of spots) for it to be removed. When user click on the image, the image will fadeOut. However, the image will re-appear after 10s later, if the user does not click on the image, the new image will not be displayed after 10s.

***what has been done:***

At each click, the image will fadeOut. Secondly, I do understand for the image to reappear after 10 seconds, should the user tap on the initial image and it disappears, I need to have the following process features:

1.) Do a conditional check, if tap image disappears, new identical image will re-appear after 10s from a setInterval function. Else, return false and do nothing until user clicks on the image.

***Issue:***

At this point, I am stuck at how to create the function call that performs the conditional check and also enable the new image to re-appear after 10s when the initial image fadesOut.

I need help. Thanks.

COde:

```js
function A() {

  var CounterInterval, counter = 0,
    timer = 30;
  var GameScore = 0,
    tap_Spots = false;

  $('#GamePage').fadeIn({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#GamePage').animate({
    'left': '0px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
    queue: false,
    complete: function() {

      $('#GameTimer').show();
      CounterInterval = setInterval(function() {
        counter = counter + 1;
        timer = timer - 1;
        $("#GameTimer").attr("src", "img/TimeLeft/Timer_" + timer + ".png");
        console.log("Time left is:" + timer);

        //End Of Game Condition
        if (timer == 0) {
          clearInterval(CounterInterval);
          $('#GamePage').fadeOut({
            duration: slideDuration,
            queue: false
          });
          $('#GamePage').animate({
            'left': '1081px'
          }, {
            duration: slideDuration,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
            queue: false
          });

          $('#ResultPage').fadeIn({
            duration: slideDuration,
            queue: false
          });
          $('#ResultPage').animate({
            'left': '0px'
          }, {
            duration: slideDuration,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
            queue: false
          });
        } else if (timer < 30 && timer > 0) {
          //Game Method
          $("#Spot_1").click(function() {

            //Remove the spots
            $("#Spot_1").fadeOut();
            console.log("blackspot is removed");
            //Increment score by 10
            GameScore = GameScore + 10;
            $("#GameScore").attr("src", "img/ScorePoint/Score_" + GameScore + ".png");

            //create Interval for spots to reappear after user clicks on spots
            if (tap_Spots == true) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                $("#Spot_1").fadeIn();
                console.log("blackspot re-appears");
              }, 3000);
            } else return false;

          });
          $("#Spot_2").click(function() {
            //create Interval for spots to reappear after user clicks on spots
            $("#Spot_2").fadeOut();
            console.log("blackspot #2 is removed");
            GameScore = GameScore + Score;
            $("#GameScore").attr("src", "lib/SKII/img/Page09/ScorePoint/Score_" + GameScore + ".png");
          });
          $("#Spot_3").click(function() {
            //create Interval for spots to reappear after user clicks on spots
          });
          $("#Spot_4").click(function() {
            //create Interval for spots to reappear after user clicks on spots
          });
          $("#Spot_5").click(function() {
            //create Interval for spots to reappear after user clicks on spots
          });
          $("#Spot_6").click(function() {
            //create Interval for spots to reappear after user clicks on spots
          });
        }
      }, 1000)
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#PlayTime {
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 150px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#Score {
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 830px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#Spot_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 940px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 450px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#Spot_2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1000px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 550px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#Spot_3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1050px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 350px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#Spot_4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1200px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 500px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#Spot_5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1160px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 630px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#Spot_6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1380px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 480px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="GamePage" style="position:absolute; z-index:11; top:0; width: 1080px; height: 1920px; margin:auto;">

  <span id="Score"><img id = "GameScore" src="img/ScorePoint/Score_0.png"></span>
  <span id="PlayTime"><img id = "GameTimer" src="img/TimeLeft/Timer_30.png"></span>

  <img id="Spot_1" src="img/Spot_01.png" />
  <img id="Spot_2" src="img/Spot_02.png" />
  <img id="Spot_3" src="img/Spot_03.png" />
  <img id="Spot_4" src="img/Spot_04.png" />
  <img id="Spot_5" src="img/Spot_05.png" />
  <img id="Spot_6" src="img/Spot_06.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: I notice a bunch of undefined variables in your example. Also what triggers `A()` to execute? What have you tried so far? Fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/a141L1u7/

Comment: @Twisty function A() is triggered when user clicks on a button in the previous page. Hence,  "GamePage" will fadeIn and and upon completion of fadeIn, will run the script within. What I have tried so far is to just simply input `$("#blackSpot_1").fadeIn();` in javascript line: 41 of jsfiddle.net/Twisty/a141L1u7.

Comment: If `A()` is triggered from an event that happens on another page, how is it triggered when this page loads. Something is not making sense here.

Comment: @Twisty when user clicks on Button A from page 1, page 2 will fadeIn. Hence, for Button A => `onclick=A();`, therefore in my function A(), you will see the fading in of gamepage which is equivalent to page 2. Therefore, for functions to be triggered in page 2, I did it via: `$('#GamePage').fadeIn({ duration: slideDuration, queue: false });
            $('#GamePage').animate({'left':'0px'}, { duration: slideDuration, easing: 'easeInOutQuart', queue: false, complete: function(){...}`,where oncomplete of fading in, the following trigger methods are called. Hope this clears all doubt

Comment: First of all, set interval doesn't guarantee you the interval time will be accurate or not, try using something relative to the time.. Or else you may encounter with some problems on some devices

Comment: @AdarshMohan you mean by using a setTimeout method call?

Comment: @luke : what i said was not an answer to your question, but it was just an information to tell you that setTimeout and setIntervall doesn't guarantee about the accuracy

Comment: @AdarshMohan Then, what is your suggestion.

Comment: take a look at this [delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: or you can refer to this question [Is there a more accurate...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196027/is-there-a-more-accurate-way-to-create-a-javascript-timer-than-settimeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  No need for separate functions for each spot, and no need for your `tap_Spots` boolean:

```js
$('img').click(function() {
  var self = this; // hold onto the clicked DOM node for later reference
  $(self).fadeOut(); // fade it out
  // do your game score stuff here
  window.setTimeout(function() { 
    $(self).fadeIn(); // setTimeout has elapsed, can fade back in
  },3000); // 3 seconds here, not 10, just for easier demo
});
```

```css
.positioner {
  width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid; display: block; float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- changed images to different urls, see comments below -->
<div class="positioner"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div class="positioner"><img src="//placehold.it/51x51"></div>
<div class="positioner"><img src="//placehold.it/49x49"></div>
<div class="positioner"><img src="//placehold.it/35x35"></div>
<div class="positioner"><img src="//placehold.it/55x55"></div>
<div class="positioner"><img src="//placehold.it/50x45"></div>
<div class="positioner"><img src="//placehold.it/52x51"></div>
<div class="positioner"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution if all the images are identical. But what if there are different image source, all image resources differ from each other??wouldn't you still need different click function for each image?

Comment: @Luke No, that is not how selectors work, the image source has nothing to do with it.  `$('img')` would match every `<img>` tag on the page regardless of any other attributes such as url (I updated the above sample code to demonstrate this.)  Presumably in real life you would want a less global selector than that -- `$('.positioner img')` would match all the images in the above code for example.

Comment: thanks. yes, I have realised that there is no need for each individual img 'id' as well. Hence, at this point , the function method call is calling on '<img>' tag rather than the individual id itself, therefore, the function method call is applicable to all associated img tags. Hence, it saves the trouble on creating boolean condition. Am i right to say that? Besides, my code is pretty heavy then. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, as far as I can tell there was never any reason for your boolean, unless you're making use of it in code not shown here. You set it to true and then almost immediately check to see whether it's true -- there's no way for it to ever be false when it reaches that `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve my own issue, and that is to set the condition `tap_Spots = true` when each spot is cicked. Hence the correct code syntax that will work:

```js
$("#Spot_1").click(function() {
  //create Interval for spots to reappear after user clicks on spots

  //Set check condition to true when spots have been clicked
  tap_Spots = true;
  
  //Remove the spots 
  $("#Spot_1").fadeOut();
  
  console.log("Spot_1 is removed");
  
  //Increment score by 10ss
  GameScore = GameScore + Score;
  $("#GameScore").attr("src", "lib/SKII/img/Page09/ScorePoint/Score_" + GameScore + ".png");

  console.log(tap_Spots);
  
  //create Interval for spots to reappear after user clicks on spots
  
  if (tap_Spots == true) {
    //reset the check condition to default
    tap_Spots = false;
    console.log("tap_Spots=true");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#Spot_1").fadeIn();
      console.log("Spot_1 re-appears");
    }, 3000);
  } else return false;
});
```