# If JavaScript is (mostly) synchronous and single threaded, why does a while loop not block execution of further statements?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript! I am trying to make an extremely naive blocking statement in a JavaScript program. I think JavaScript is single threaded (mostly, except for things like setTimeout), and synchronous within a code block, so I expected that I could block execution of my code with a while loop. I do not want to use setTimeout because I'm not sure it will be reliably precise enough to do what I want.

Let me explain. I have a button with `class="playback"`, which should trigger a series of sounds to play. The callback makes an AJAX request, and then hands data to `playbackRecording()`. This function accepts a list of objects which have two attributes: `key_pressed` (helps determines which sound to play, but is not important for this issue), and `time_to_next_key` (how many milliseconds to wait until the next sound is played). `actionApp()` is the function that causes the sound to actually get played.

**My expectation:** The first sound is played. Then a short amount of time passes and the next action happens. Repeat until finished.

**What actually happens:** An amount of time elapses that equals the sum of time_to_next_key for all keypresses, then all the sounds are played at the end.

```js
function playbackRecording(content) {
    var waitTime = 0;
    var keypress = content[0];
    actionApp(keypress.key_pressed);

    for (var i = 1; i < content.length; i++) {
        waitTime += keypress.time_to_next_key;
        keypress = content[i];

        var end = Date.now() + waitTime;

        while(Date.now() < end) {}
        actionApp(keypress.key_pressed);
    }
}

function playbackLinkClicked(evt) {
    var urlString = '/fetch_recording/' + this.id;

    $.get(urlString, function(data){
        if (data.status === 'success') {
            playbackRecording(data.content);
        } else {
            alert('Could not load recording.');
        }
    });
}

$('.playback').click(playbackLinkClicked);
```

What I am missing?

Comment: How are you triggering the sounds? It may be that the triggering process is being blocked by your while loop.

Comment: Probably, the sounds are played asynchronously. So your synchronous code blocks the sounds.

Comment: Learn about the event loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop .

Comment: JavaScript is pretty bad for stuff that depends on super accurate timing.. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196027/is-there-a-more-accurate-way-to-create-a-javascript-timer-than-settimeout But if you know for sure that your code will execute within the interval, then you can probably get away with using setInterval. See here for a great explanation of how setInterval works: http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: *"I do not want to use setTimeout because I'm not sure it will be reliably precise enough to do what I want."* - Use it anyway. Don't use `setInterval()` if you want precise control, use `setTimeout()` and calculate the appropriate delay based on the current time. A blocking loop like `while(Date.now() < end) {}` is always a bad idea because it freezes the whole browser, giving a bad user experience.

Comment: If you have to "wait" for playback of an audio clip to finish, you can use an [onended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) event handler on the audio element (the "ended" event is sent when the "ended" attribute is set) . If you need silence between sound clips, use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). Don't use blocking loops ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playing the sound is done by asynchronous code (I don't know exactly what `actionApp()` does, but the behavior you describe is consistent with this, and it's how most interactive code works in Javascript). So when you call `actionApp()`, it's putting this code on the event queue. It will not actually play anything until Javascript returns to the main event loop.

The `while` loop is synchronous, so your code doesn't return until all of them are finished. Each time it calls `actionApp()` it adds another sound to the event queue. Then when it finishes, all the queued actions get executed.