# Need help finding the time left on a setTimeout function being used to continuously loop between webpages

Tags: javascript, iframe, timer, settimeout, countdowntimer

I am currently using the javascript setTimeout function to continuously loop through the same 4 different websites every 10 seconds.  I need an accurate way to show a countdown timer of how many seconds are left before the next website is displayed.  Is there a way to subtract the time being used in the setTimeout function already being used to create the timer?  Here is the current Javascript that I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pages = [
'webpage 1',
'webpage 2',
'webpage 3',
'webpage 4'
], p = pages.length;
while(--p > -1){
(function(p){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = pages[p];
    pages[p] = a;
})(p);
}
function loadIframe() {
var page = pages[(p = ++p % pages.length)], bust = 'bustcache=' + new 
Date().getTime();
page = page.search? page.href + '&' + bust : page.href + '?' + bust;
document.getElementById('if_one').src = page;
setTimeout(loadIframe, 10000);
}
loadIframe();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, here is what I came up with.

```js
var pages = [
  'webpage 1',
  'webpage 2',
  'webpage 3',
  'webpage 4'
];
var seconds = 10;
var pageIndex = 0;
var el = document.querySelector('p');
var div = document.querySelector('div');
render(seconds, pageIndex);

setInterval(function() {
  seconds--;
  if (seconds === 0) {
    seconds = 10;
    pageIndex++;
    if (pageIndex > pages.length-1) { pageIndex=0 }
  }
  render(seconds, pageIndex);
}, 1000);

function render(sec, pIndex) {
  el.textContent = sec + ' seconds remain...';
  div.textContent = pages[pIndex];
}
```

```html
<h1>Count down</h1>

<p>Please wait...</p>
<div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding:20px">Page</div>
```

I used `setInterval` so that the timer is always counting down by decrementing `seconds` variable and rendering to every second.

If the 10 second interval has reached 0, we reset the timer back to 10 and increment the page index.

You can imagine the `pages` array actually has `page1.html` or whatever the URL is to load and the `render` function could set the `iframe.src` to that url.

Comment: The timer works great but it stops at 0.  Is it possible to get it to refresh and countdown from 10 to 0 again at the same speed as the webpages are changing?

Comment: @DustinVondross I updated my answer. Please consider upvoting or accepting as the correct answer if this answers your question.

Comment: I had to go back to the setTimeout for the webpage looping because I need it to continuously loop between the four webpages.  When I use the setTimeout for the webpage looping and your setInterval for the timer it is almost spot on but after about an hour or so it is a second off.  Imagine this time would continue to grow.

Comment: `setTimeout` is not meant for accuracy. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/196027/266535) for some ideas on how to implement for accuracy.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see an example though?

Comment: I don't need to use setTimeout if I don't have to, just haven't found a way to continuously loop between the different websites.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

While you can't see it directly from `setTimeout()`, it's easy enough to just record the start time and do a little math:

```
const delay = 10000;
const start = Date.now(); // milliseconds
setTimeout(doSomething, delay);

// when needed
const elapsed = Date.now() - start;
const remaining = delay - elapsed; // divide by 1000 for seconds
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.  This is the JavaScript right?  What would the HTML element look like?

Comment: You would just periodically call `setInterval()` or any of a number of other methods and then just set the text of a `<div>` or something. There are lots of different ways to go about it. The value of `remaining` is just a number for us elsewhere.

Comment: Not having any luck, is this how I would call it? <div id="remaining"> </div>