# Why is the native NodeJS setInterval() function so inaccurate when its possible to be highly accurate?

Tags: node.js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/accurate-interval

This module will make sure that the interval is accurate forever. Why doesnt the native setInterval function work similiarly?

Comment: But it corrects itself for the next callback though. AFAIK setInterval doesnt

Comment: I really doubt, the mentioned package can be `accurate forever`, given how javascript is implemented (atleast in v8). Having said that, it could be `javascript` implementation dependent

Comment: Of course there are ways to make it inaccurate on purpose but given you dont intentionally screw it up (or block the event loop accidentally), it will continue to be accurate. (Nothing runs FOREVER)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196027/is-there-a-more-accurate-way-to-create-a-javascript-timer-than-settimeout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript

Comment: @lifeisfoo I'd like to know WHY its not implemented accurately then. Is it too preserve legacy behaviour?

Comment: It's by design. Please read more [about the js event loop](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-understanding-node-js-event-loop/) to better understand why it works in this way.

Comment: I understand the event loop. You dont understand my question though. SetInterval has a clear functionality. It fails however to consistantly provide said functionality. There are ways (like in the mentioned module) to provide the functionatlity consistantly. My question is, why wasnt setInterval implemented properly in nodeJS when they had a chance too make it better than the implementation in the browser. Is it so that it stays consistent with the browser behaviour?