# How to create an accurate setTimeout (not interval) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, timeout, electron

I need to create a 'select by hover' (dwell) effect in my application and it is crucial to be timely and accurate. This needs to trigger just once for every timeout call and must not loop. The dwell function is attached to an element (getElementById).

My implementation at the moment sometimes works brilliantly and sometimes takes a lot of time to complete. Sometimes the callback just doesn't trigger after the setTimeout.

```
dwell: (elem, select) => {
   var timeout = 0
    elem.onmouseover = () => {
      timeout = setTimeout(select, dwellTime)
    }

    elem.onmouseout = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
    }
  }
```

The select callback function must execute EXACTLY after the dwellTime has elapsed. Any ideas please?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196027/is-there-a-more-accurate-way-to-create-a-javascript-timer-than-settimeout

Comment: Browsers are not real-time platforms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a more accurate way to create a Javascript timer than setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196027/is-there-a-more-accurate-way-to-create-a-javascript-timer-than-settimeout)

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded and non-preemptive. If it's busy doing something else when the timeout is reached, it won't interrupt it to execute the timer function.

Comment: Any ideas on alternatives I can use for this?

Comment: @Danielmt Welcome to SO! At this point it seems to me that it becomes more of an X/Y problem: you want a hover-to-select feature, you use setTimeout to implement it, there are some issues and you blame setTimeout (with some reason, but that is a limitation of JS). To find a suitable workaround, we would need more details about your issue (ideally an MCVE) and explanations about what compromise you can make.